# concatinating 1 string and an int value while giving id value to a <button> field which is generated dynamically in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
var but = document.createElement('span');

        but.innerHTML.id="but1"+inc;

        but.innerHTML = '<button value="delete row" id="'but'+inc"  
onclick="deleteRow(this.id)">delete row</button>';

// '"but"+inc' , "but+inc" are not working

//here inc is an integer value which increments by one
```

Comment: `// '"but"+inc' , "but+inc" are not working` indicates you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how things work...

Answer (score 3):

this is wrong

```
  but.innerHTML.id="but1"+inc;
```

this is how it should be

```
  but.id="but1"+inc;

  but.innerHTML = '<button value="delete row" id="but'+inc+'" onclick="deleteRow(this.id)">delete row</button>';
```